# Grep not working for strings with numbers and spaces

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, grep

I am trying to print all the following entries in my file

```
show initial all#Total brb Errors Received#g1/1 
show initial all#Total brb Errors Received#g0/2 
show initial all#Total brb Errors Received#g0/3
show initial all#Total brb Errors Received#g4/3
```

Since my string had a space I wrote the grep in following format so that I get expected output

```
grep "show initial all#Total brb Errors Received#g*/*" inputfile > output file
```

Any inputs?

Comment: Remember that in regular expressions, `*` isn't by itself a wildcard. It means "the preceding character, zero or more times". So when you write `#g*/*` it would match `#`, `#g`, `#/`, `#gggggg///////`, etc.

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
grep -E 'show initial all#Total brb Errors Received#g[[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+' inputfile > output file
```

or;

```
grep -E 'show initial all#Total brb Errors Received#g[0-9]+/[0-9]+"' inputfile > output file
```

The `-E` means use 'extended regular expressions'.  The `+` means look for 'one or more' or the previous expression, which is (in both cases) a regex (character class) that matches a single digit.

Note that if you only want single digits matched, then you omit the `+` (twice in each regex), and the `-E` option becomes unnecessary (the regex works the same both with and without the `-E` option).

It's generally safer to use single quotes rather than double quotes around arguments, especially regular expression arguments.  There are exceptions (such as when you need to get the value of a shell variable included in the regex), but use single quotes when possible.